Error C3867 non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
I'm trying to insert a class function into the map value, but I get an error:
Error   C3867   'ActionsOnTheDictionary::select': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

All methods except select work, but they don't lie in the class either.
Here is the code in main():
std::map< std::string, std::map< std::string, size_t > > mapDictionaries;

using namespace std::placeholders;
ActionsOnTheDictionary A(mapDictionaries);

std::map< std::string, std::function < void(std::map< std::string, std::map< std::string, size_t > >& , std::istream&, std::ostream&) > > command;
{
  command["help"] = std::bind(printCommands);
  command["create"] = createDictionary, mapDictionaries, _1, _2;
  command["delete"] = deleteDictionary, mapDictionaries, _1, _2;
  command["list"] = printNamesDictionaries, mapDictionaries, _1, _2;
  command["add"] = add, mapDictionaries, _1, _2;
  command["unite"] = unite, mapDictionaries, _1, _2;
  command["rename"] = rename, mapDictionaries, _1, _2;
  command["clear"] = clear, mapDictionaries, _1, _2;
  command["select"] = A.select, mapDictionaries, _1, _2; //Error

}

Here is the code of the class itself:
class ActionsOnTheDictionary
{
public:
    ActionsOnTheDictionary(std::map< std::string, std::map< std::string, size_t > > & dictionary);
    ~ActionsOnTheDictionary() = default;

    void select(mapDictionaries_t& mapDictionaries, std::istream& in, std::ostream& out);

private:
    std::map< std::string, std::map< std::string, size_t > >& SelectedDictionary;
};

ActionsOnTheDictionary::ActionsOnTheDictionary(std::map< std::string, std::map< std::string, size_t > >& dictionary) :
    SelectedDictionary(dictionary)
{}
void ActionsOnTheDictionary::select(mapDictionaries_t& mapDictionaries, std::istream & in, std::ostream & out)
{

}

I tried using std::bind(), but nothing worked, either.

Can you explain what the intention was of writing command["create"] = createDictionary, mapDictionaries, _1, _2;? Everything after the comma does nothing. Did you forget to write the call to std::bind on everything but the first line?

The function is named ActionsOnTheDictionary::select and you will need to pass the instance, A in as an argument. Probably easiest to do this with a capturing lambda. Can't really answer this one because I have no ing clue what you're doing. The code makes too little sense.

I think, our telepath had a conniption here. Is this a map of functions which takes a map of maps as argument?

I think you may need to reframe this question as a "How do I...?" What you are doing is wrong in several ways, so inferring your intent is difficult and answering only the question asked will not get you any further ahead. Please fully and clearly describe what you are trying to accomplish.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=C3867+non-standard. Generally, when you have an error, throw it at a search engine and browse some of the results.

Side note: The error tells you exactly how to get rid of the error, but you'll just be trading it for a new one or code that compiles, but misbehaves at runtime.

By the time you have a map of maps used as a function parameter, it's usually time for a typedef somewhere.

You are misusing std::bind() for command["help"], as there is no useful use-case where std::bind() is used with no parameters to bind to the specified callable.
Also, you are completely missing std::bind() on all of the other commands where you try to use std::placeholders. You are invoking the comma operator, which doesn't do what you think it does.
In the case of command["select"], you can't use A.select the way you are trying to.  You have to use &ActionsOnTheDictionary::select instead, and you will have to bind &A as the 1st parameter for select's this pointer.  Otherwise, just use a lambda instead of std::bind().
Try this instead:
using map_type = std::map< std::string, std::map< std::string, size_t > >;

map_type mapDictionaries;
ActionsOnTheDictionary A(mapDictionaries);

std::map< std::string, std::function < void(map_type&, std::istream&, std::ostream&) > > command;
command["help"] = printCommands;
command["create"] = createDictionary;
command["delete"] = deleteDictionary;
command["list"] = printNamesDictionaries;
command["add"] = add;
command["unite"] = unite;
command["rename"] = rename;
command["clear"] = clear;

using namespace std::placeholders;
command["select"] = std::bind(&ActionsOnTheDictionary::select, &A, _1, _2, _3);
// or:
command["select"] = [&A](mapDictionaries_t& mapDictionaries, std::istream& in, std::ostream& out) {
                        A.select(mapDictionaries, in, out);
                    };

